# Фильтр атрибутов для каждой категории отдельно

Tags: wordpress

Столкнулся с трудностями фильтров по атрибутам в каждой категории. То есть, нужно при открытии стиральных машин фильтр условно "Объем барабана: n" или "Скорость оборотов: n" для категории миксера.
У меня через апишку подтягиваются товары с 1С, вместе с атрибутами. Плагины предлагают только стандартные фильтра.
Нашел плагин  WC Ajax Product Filter, но он уже выглядит весьма устаревшим. Кто-то сталкивался с такой потребностью, как вы ее решили или какой плагин для этого использовали. Заранее благодарю всех откликнувшихся.

Comment: Множество плагинов это умеют. Причём реализовать можно  разными способами Подбирай что тебя устроит.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woof-by-category/